# The most efficient MySQL query to get n models with m child models?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a many to many relationship of `photos` to `categories` via `lightboxes`.

`photos` to `lightboxes` is many to many, `categories` to `lightboxes` is one to one.

The `photos` and `lightboxaphotos` pivot table both have millions of records.

What I need to do is for each category, which has a lightbox id, get the first three photos to show as a preview.

To do this in one query, I am currently doing this with `UNION`, like so:

```sql
(
SELECT
        photo_id,
        photo_name,
        category_name,
        category_id,
        category_parent_id,
        lightbox_id
    FROM
        photos
    LEFT JOIN lightboxphotos ON photo_id = lightboxphoto_photo_id
    LEFT JOIN categories ON lightboxphoto_lightbox_id = lightbox_id
WHERE
    lightboxphoto_lightbox_id = 123
ORDER BY
    lightboxphoto_sortorder ASC
LIMIT 3)
UNION (
    SELECT
        photo_id,
        photo_name,
        category_name,
        category_id,
        category_parent_id,
        lightbox_id
    FROM
        photos
    LEFT JOIN lightboxphotos ON photo_id = lightboxphoto_photo_id
    LEFT JOIN categories ON lightboxphoto_lightbox_id = lightbox_id
WHERE
    lightboxphoto_lightbox_id = 345
ORDER BY
    lightboxphoto_sortorder ASC
LIMIT 3)
UNION 
-- ... etc for each category
```

Currently this takes about 1.8 seconds to run for 10 categories. The number of categories may hit the 100+ mark. I will use caching, but what I'm most interested in in the first place is using the most efficient query. How do I make this more efficient?

I don't know much about raw MySQL, as usually I would let Laravel handle this, but I'm on a legacy project that doesn't use Laravel.

Comment: Which version of MySQL do you use? You may be able to use the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) windowing function, but it's only available in MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.3+.

Comment: What would that code look like? I have mysql 8 on some repos I work on